# Fragment is always null in oncreate even with setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I wanted to have some data persistent, and I followed Developer Guide [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) and created a data Fragment class, to save all my data.

In onCreate I'm using following logic to determine if Data Fragment is null or not (also described in developers guide):

```
 find the retained fragment on activity restarts
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

// create the fragment and data the first time
if (dataFragment == null) {
    // add the fragment
    dataFragment = new DataFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
    // load the data from the web
    dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
} else {
    //loading data from dataRestoreFragment
}
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

but dataFrag is always NULL, even after oriention change !
what is wrong here ?

EDIT:

The datafragment code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

I have to mention, if I check for the datafrag after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); it will work and return the correct fragment, but the problem is, My another fragment which is ListFragment, its adaptor will get called before restoring data, so that I can not load data into that Fragment, and the fragment will not have data and cause the app to crash !
and If place the code before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), it would be executed before Listfragment adaptor but it is null !

so how can I fix this ?

Comment: See if you enabled "Don't keep activities" in Settings > Developer options on your device or emulator.

Comment: No, it is not checked @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

> if I check for the datafrag after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); it will work and return the correct fragment

Then do that.

> My another fragment which is ListFragment, its adaptor will get called before restoring data, so that I can not load data into that Fragment, and the fragment will not have data and cause the app to crash !

Then your "get called" logic is in the wrong method within that fragment. You need to move that logic later in the fragment's lifecycle, such as `onViewCreated()` or `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I ended up making all of my fragments setRetainInstance(true), and now I'm able to use the app in landscape mode as well, but I couldn't make using only one frag for data

Answer (score -1):

try to add something like this;

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   dataFragment.setData(collectMyLoadedData());
}
```

Comment: when will this method be called ?
before onDestroy ?
I have saved data in onDestroy, but fragment is null in activity's onCreate method, before super.onCreate

Comment: this method handles orientation changes